# Number Guessing game PHP not functoning

Tags: php

I am trying to write a php game that raises an random (`$secretNumber`) number between 1 and 100, prints it to the screen, prints a form with buttons for the user to select either 'higher' 'lower' or 'correct'. Upon a button press, the outside values are altered accordingly and the computer raises another random number between the lowest and highest values. This continues until the user select correct and the game resets. 
I am using a session to ensure that the values don't reset each time a button is clicked.
My problem is that the `$secretNumber` resets a couple of times before the `$_SESSION` locks it in.
Also the `$randomGuess` doesn't seem to lock in before updating.

Any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<?php
$low = 1;
$high = 100;
//create a function to hold a random number, between 1 and 100  and save it 
//to a session variable.
secretNumber();

function secretNumber(){ //********** secretNumber() **********
 global $randomGuess;
        if(!isset($_SESSION["secretNumber"])){
        $secretNumber = rand(1,100);
        $_SESSION['secretNumber'] = $secretNumber;
    } else {
        $secretNumber = $_SESSION["secretNumber"];
        echo($_SESSION['secretNumber']);
    }

    echo 'Secret number is '.$secretNumber;
    echo '  <br/>  ';
    }                   //********** end secretNumber() ***********

    //create a function to create a random guess as to the value of the 
    //first random number

randomGuess();

function randomGuess() { //********** randomGuess() **********
 global $randomGuess;
 global $low;
 global $high;

if (isset($_SESSION['low'])){
        $low = $_SESSION['low'];
} 
if (isset($_SESSION['high'])){
        $high = $_SESSION['high'];
}
    $randomGuess = round($high-(($high-$low)/2));
    echo 'Random guess is '.$randomGuess;
    echo "<br/>";
    $_SESSION['randomGuess'] = $randomGuess;
    }                   // ********** end randomGuess() **********

//create a function to provide a response as to whether the guess is low, 
//high or correct, and adjust the limits of the random guess accordingly.

checkGuess();

function checkGuess() { // ********** checkGuess() **********
 global $low;
 global $high;
 global $randomGuess;

// form to show a 'high' button, a 'low' button and a 'correct' button
// Correct button needs to reset $_SESSION["secretNumber"], and start 
// process over.

    print <<<HERE
        <div>
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <form method = "post" action = ""  style="width:35%; 
       padding-left:35%">
                    <fieldset>

                        <button type = "submit" value="high" name ="high">Too High</button> <br/><br/>
                        <button type = "submit" value="low" name = "low">Too Low</button> <br/><br/>
                        <button type = "submit" value="correct" name = "correct">Correct</button> <br/><br/>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>  
HERE;

    if (isset($_POST['low'])) {
                echo "low <br/>";
                echo "randomGuess = ".$randomGuess. "<br/>";
                unset($_SESSION["low"]);
                $low = $randomGuess;
                $_SESSION['low'] = $low;
                unset($_SESSION["randomNumber"]);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['high'])){
                echo "high <br/>";
                echo "randomGuess = ".$randomGuess. "<br/>";
                unset($_SESSION["high"]);
                $high = $randomGuess;
                $_SESSION['high'] = $high;
                unset($_SESSION["randomNumber"]);
    }
 } //                   ********** end checkGuess() **********

if (isset($_POST['correct'])){
            print <<<HERE
            <h2>Yes I guessed the correct secret number. Your secret is out</h2>
    HERE;
        unset($_SESSION["secretNumber"]);// unset the random number as the guess was correct.
            unset($_SESSION["high"]);
            unset($_SESSION["low"]);
        }//end if

echo "low =".$low."<br/>";
echo "high =".$high." <br/>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if `$secretNumber` is same as session.

`var_dump($secretNumber);`

`if($secretNumber != $_SESSION["secretNumber"]) {
    echo "Restart is here";
}`

Test it after every function and then you can see what is problem.

Comment: Thanks proofzy, I tried that, added the 'global $secretNumber;' to the secretNumber() function and the value passed through showing the value in the var_dump as it should. However, when the program first runs, the value for $secretNumber changes upon the first button press. The value for the randomGuess also does not pass through when the high or low button is pressed, but the value put into the $low or $high is the next guess .

Comment: After much trial and error, and using var_dump() to see what the values of the variables were at each stage, I added a function call to randomGuess() to have another guess after  the 'low' or 'high' button was pressed, as well as adding a reset when the correct guess was recognised. The trick was a bit of lateral thinking as well as following the values of each variable through the program.